# failed to replace value on specific columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am working on a dataset with different type of data inside. When trying to do some replacements like replacing empty value ("") to NA, error msg shows.

```
> xDT1[xDT1==""]<- NA
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Mostly related to as.POSITct etc. So I tried to pick out the right columns, and do the replacement. the elements were right, but the combination(chain) showed the error msg. 
I have tried the sapply, lapply method as other post suggested, yet I think the issue is about how the value is to pass into, rather than the apply function.
Still feel confused.
Please advise, and many thanks.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
xDT1 <- data.table(date=as.POSIXct(paste0("2018-1-",sep=1:12)),SN=1:12, Val=rnorm(12) ,  # simulation of date, SN, and Value
                           Tag1=factor(rep(letters[4:6],2)),Tag2=factor(rep(LETTERS[9:11],2)))   # simulation of tags

xDT1[3,4] <- ""   # arbitrarily assign empty value 
xDT1[7,5] <- ""   # arbitrarily assign empty value

xDT1str <- lapply(xDT1,class) %>% unlist;xDT1str         # get the class of each column
xWch1 <- names(xDT1str[which(xDT1str=="factor")])        # get the colnames of the "factorized" columns
xDT1[xDT1==""]<- NA                                      # Failed as described
xDT1[,.SD,.SDcols=xWch1]                                 # worked
xDT1[,.SD,.SDcols=xWch1]==""                             # worked
xDT1[,.SD,.SDcols=xWch1][xDT1[,.SD,.SDcols=xWch1]==""] <- NA  #Failed when chained.
```

the error msg is,

```
> xDT1[,.SD,.SDcols=xWch1][xDT1[,.SD,.SDcols=xWch1]==""] <- NA
Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , .SD, .SDcols = xWch1, value = list( : 
  unused argument (.SDcols = xWch1)
```

Comment: Your first error has nothing to do with data.table. You would get the same error for a data.frame. The error occurs because you are comparing columns of different classes (e.g. POSIXt with a character), R, has a built in mechanism to convert the RHS to the class of the LHS in order to compare apples with apples, hence, he tries `as.POSIXct("")` (converting your RHS statement to the class of the LHS) and as a result, you are getting this error. As a side note, this is not how we usually update values in data.table

Comment: A reproducible example would help.

Comment: @Christoph There is a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidArenburg . So I avoided to do it on all dataset. You are right, nothing to do with data.table. I am new to R, would like to learn more skill for experienced engineers like you are. Many thanks.

Comment: @Christoph , it is the sample code I made for review, only the last sentence will get wrong msg. Thanks.